# Implement OnClickListener

Tags: java, android, onclicklistener

I'm reading an Android's tutorial and I have a class that implements abstract class OnClickListener. The problem is that in tutorial when it override method onClick,this has only one parameter but my eclipse show me an error because the onClick method need two parameters.

Below my wrong code by tutorial,how Can I fix it?

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity implements OnClickListener {
/** Called when the activity is first created. */
@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    final Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.form_button);
    button.setOnClickListener((android.view.View.OnClickListener) this);
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

public void onClick(View v) {
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.form_button:
        final EditText edit_name = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_name);
        final EditText edit_lastname = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.edit_lastname);
        Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
        bundle.putString("name", edit_name.getText().toString());
        bundle.putString("lastname", edit_lastname.getText().toString());
        Intent form_intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), Form.class);
        form_intent.putExtras(bundle);
        startActivity(form_intent);
        break;
    }

}

}
```

Comment: onClick requires only one param that is the view sure you have the right imports??

Comment: You must have imported the wrong package - onClick() needs only one parameter. Can you show us your imports?

Comment: Ok thanks so much I was wrong in import package.

Comment: import android.view.View; I think that's it

Comment: @StefanoMaglione any change you have `import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener`??

Comment: The listed code does not seem to be right.  do you mean public class MainActivity extends Activity implements View.OnClickListener

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to import

```
 import android.view.View.OnClickListener
```

and not

```
 import android.content.DialogInterface.OnClickListener
```

I guess you have the wrong import of DialogInterface.OnClickListener

`onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which)` takes 2 param

But View.OnClickListener's `onClick` takes only 1 param ie View

http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html

Comment: Thank you. I spent at least an hour on this, having automatically included imports, following Android Studio's hints and getting nowhere.

Answer (score 2):

You may mistakenly imported the onClickListener on `DialogInterface`. You have to import `android.view.onClickListener`, because Button is a sub-class of View.

For more details check this [`link`](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/View.OnClickListener.html).

Answer (score 0):

or do as below

```
implements View.OnClickListener
```